# Qual a diferença entre Model::where('id','=',1)->get() para Model::query()->where('id','=',1)->get()?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Então eu acabei notando que algumas pessoas usam Model::query()... enquanto umas usan só Model::... e eu não sei qual a sua diferença e se algum modo é melhor que o outro.

Comment: _algumas pessoas usam..._ - isso por si só não é um critério muito bom para definir como deve fazer (apesar de que já caiu num laravel...). Idealmente tem que olhar sempre a documentação, e seguir o modo descrito nela. Nesse seu caso dá na mesma, o `query()` está implícito no uso do `where`, então não tem razão de por. Pode fazer algum sentido chamar diretamente num caso onde tem uma série de encadeamentos com if, e outras condições: `$querybuilder = Model::query();` (query "vazia") seguido de uma série de ifs que mude as combinações de  `$querybuilder->where...` etc

Comment: Não existe diferença, porque os dois retonar um Query Builder.  Leia [https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries)

Answer (score -3):

Nunca pensei nisso mas eu uso query() pois assim eu consigo ter ajuda da IDE para ver todos os métodos disponíveis enquanto com Model::where eu não tenho, também para uma questão de organização pois sempre uso Model::query() e faço uma chama por linha

```
Model::query()
    ->select("*")
    ->where("id", "=", 1)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score -3):

Acredito que o mais correto seria entender o que cada método encadeado faz a luz da documentação, porque em ambos os caso o resultado será o mesmo:

```php
Model::where()->get();
```

Esse `get()` retorna uma instância de `Illuminate\Support\Collection` enquanto `where()` retorna uma instância de `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`

Desse ponto são duas coisas diferentes, a collection reestrutura o resultado da pesquisa dos dados gerados a partir do query builder que por sua vez entre suas responsabilidades está o ato de construir as consultas sqls.

Quando você utiliza `Model::query();` você está iniciando uma nova consulta a partir do `Builder` do eloquente e é essa instância que disponibiliza os métodos: `where()`, `join()` etc, quando você usa `Model::where()` o próprio eloquent inicia a consulta internamente em outras palavras é apenas um atalho/abreviação de `Model::query()->where();`, porem `query()` geralmente é usado para construir consultas mais complexas, com varias cláusulas, enquanto a segunda forma é mais simples e direta

É bem difícil eu começar a usar model a partir de `Model::query()`, geralmente sempre uso o método `where()`